# Почему выводит не все флаги

Tags: c#

Есть готовые enum-ы

```
[Flags]
public enum UserFlags {
    guest = 0, // GUEST USER             //
        normal = 1, // NORMAL USER (DEFAULT)  //
        banned = 2, // USER IS BLOCKED        //
        online = 4 // USER IS ONLINE         //
}
```

Вот так устанавливаю флаги:

```
user.Flags = UserData.UserFlags.normal;
user.SetFlag(UserData.UserFlags.guest);
user.SetFlag(UserData.UserFlags.online);

public UserFlags Flags {
    get;
    internal set;
}

public void SetFlag(UserFlags flag, bool state = true) {
    Flags = state ? Flags |= flag : Flags &= ~flag;
}
```

Но если я пробую вывести Flags как тест в консоль от возвращает только Online и Normal а вот guest не учитывается.Почему?

Comment: Вы уверены, что это C?...

Comment: @Harry извиняюсь поправил

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что флагом `guest` вы пытаетесь оперировать с несуществующим 0-вым битом.
Решение достаточно простое - начинать с 1-го бита:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserFlags {
    guest = 1, // GUEST USER             //
    normal = 2, // NORMAL USER (DEFAULT)  //
    banned = 4, // USER IS BLOCKED        //
    online = 8 // USER IS ONLINE         //
}
```

другой вариант - использовать битовый сдвиг, чтобы не путаться в значениях когда флагов достаточно много и они становятся достаточно крупными числами:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserFlags {
    guest = 1 << 0, // GUEST USER             //
    normal = 1 << 1, // NORMAL USER (DEFAULT)  //
    banned = 1 << 2, // USER IS BLOCKED        //
    online = 1 << 3 // USER IS ONLINE         //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ToString()` не обрабатывает `enum` со значением `0` и не выводит в консоль